# Mock custom error response object jasmine-Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have one function in the HTTP service which handles all HTTP errors which take custom objects and based on the specific condition its displaying the error.

service function

```
  get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    params.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}${path}`, { params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }


 public formatErrors = (error: any, apiSource) => {
    
    // based on the conditions allowing error to display
    if (error.url === `*********`) {  
      const request = error.error.request.data;
     if(request.hasOwnProperty('TITLE_NBR'))) {
        this.toastr.error(msg);
        return throwError(error.error);
      }
    }
}
```

Note: I have shown only some parts of formatErrors function.

Unit test:

```
 it("should throw error", () => {     
        service.apiSource = 'Registration';
        let htttpResp = {};
        service.get('****url******').subscribe({
            next: null,
            error: (error) => {
                console.log('error', error);
                expect(true).toEqual(true);
            },
        });
        let req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${service.url}`);
        const httpErrorResponse = {
            error: {
                request: {
                    data: {
                        TITLE_NBR: '12112'
                    }
                }
            },
            url: `${service.url}`,
            status: 404,
            statusText: 'error'

        };
   
        req.flush('', httpErrorResponse);
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
```

error:**Cannot read properties of null (reading 'request')**

not able to to read    **const request = error.error.request.data;** into formatErrors

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
const httpErrorResponse = {
            error: {
                request: {
                    data: {
                        TITLE_NBR: '12112'
                    }
                }
            },
            url: `${service.url}`,
            status: 404,
            statusText: 'error'

        };
```

Can you try:

```
const httpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
  error: {
   // error object
  },
  url: `${service.url}`,
  status: 404,
  statusText: 'error'
});
```

I am thinking if it's constructed the same as how Angular constructs the errors, it should help.

Also, can you `console.log(error)` and see what you get? This could provide a big clue as well.

Comment: i have tried with new HttpErrorResponse() but no luck and error remain same

Comment: Did the console.log show you how `errror` looks like? Any hints?

Comment: its one-line statement "Type Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'request')"

Comment: Some how the error is not the object we mock but it's `null`. Sorry, I am not sure.